# How do I add columns of group counts in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame where each id may be repeated, and each row is a transaction, with cost and size listed per transaction. I want to make a data frame where the rows are each purchaser's name, the row name to be the cost, and the value to be the number of times each name incurred each cost. I can make it as a table, but am having trouble turning that table into a data frame accurately. I've done this with collapses in other programs, but can't seem to get it right in r. Code below:

```
test.base <- data.frame(
              names=c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C"),
              size =c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

test.match<- data.frame(
              names=c("A", "B", "C"),
              cost =c(7, 8, 9))

test.merge<- merge(test.base, test.match)

#How do I make a new vriable in test-match that is the number of times 
#the cost shows up in each variable to be three new columns ("7", "8", "9")?
  table(test.merge$names, test.merge$cost)
```

Or do I need a collapse?

Edit:
I'd like an output like this the following, but as a data.frame

```
    7 8 9
  A 1 0 0
  B 0 2 0
  C 0 0 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edit, perhaps you're just looking for `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(table(test.merge$names, test.merge$cost))
  7 8 9
A 1 0 0
B 0 2 0
C 0 0 3
```

Note that the first "column" are "rownames", not an actual column.

---

Other options include using `unclass` and either `data.frame` or `as.data.frame`. The former will create syntactically valid names by prepending the names with "X" when necessary, and converting spaces to dots and so on:

```
> data.frame(unclass(table(test.merge$names, test.merge$cost)))
  X7 X8 X9
A  1  0  0
B  0  2  0
C  0  0  3
> as.data.frame(unclass(table(test.merge$names, test.merge$cost)))
  7 8 9
A 1 0 0
B 0 2 0
C 0 0 3
```

Comment: Nice.  I futxed around with various as.XXX but was unaware of the `as.data.frame.matrix`.  +1

Comment: I didn't know to put the .matrix on the end either; wish I had asked this 4 hours ago!! Thx!

Comment: @TylerRinker, it turns out `unclass` works for this problem too.